# Are there any scenarios that a controller clear different aircraft at the same altitude?

Tags: air-traffic-control

In the real world, are there any scenarios that the controller clear the same altitude or flight level to different aircraft at the same time?

Comment: Your question is answered in the link on the comment above on the "Summary" paragraph. Please have a look and if you still have any questions, please edit your post to make it more specific.

Comment: Clear and thanks!